# How to avoid node-gyp rebuild when running yarn install?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, node-gyp, rebuild, node-addon-api

When I run `yarn install`, my native add on is always rebuilt. It can be seen that the command `node-gyp rebuild` is run instead of `node-gyp build`, even if nothing is updated.

```
caros@ubuntu:~/Developer/xviz-converter$ yarn install
yarn install v1.16.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
$ node-gyp rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@10.16.0 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
....
```

How to let yarn run `node-gyp build` instead of `node-gyp rebuild`? The complete rebuild is quite time-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the install command and ignore scripts. **Note that this might break other libraries.**

```
yarn install --ignore-scripts
```

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-ignore-scripts

> Do not execute any scripts defined in the project package.json and its dependencies.